# InnoDB trigger deadlocks itself?

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.7, deadlock

I have a MySQL 5.7.22 database using the InnoDB engine.

There's a table `respondents` that has 6 associated triggers - three of them make CRUD operations on a `completed_respondents` table, and the other three do so on `respondent_stats` (shown below for their relevance).

I've been noticing some deadlock errors on the application logs (specifically, `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` in different parts of the codebase), and enabling deadlock printing on the DB yields things like the one below.

For what I understand, there are two different transactions mentioned (each of them executing a different trigger).

`Transaction (1)` is waiting on a lock:

```
(1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 325 page no 8 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `surveda`.`respondent_stats` trx id 22600376 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
```

But, *as far as I understand*, it doesn't *hold* any lock (given the lack of a `(1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S)` section).

`Transaction (2)` does hold a lock:

```
(2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

RECORD LOCKS space id 325 page no 8 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `surveda`.`respondent_stats` trx id 22600374 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
```

And it's blocked waiting on a lock that, to me, *seems to be exactly that very same one*:

```
(2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 325 page no 8 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `surveda`.`respondent_stats` trx id 22600374 lock_mode X waiting
```

I've read answers stating that triggers run in the same transaction as the query that generated them (and that queries run in an implicit transaction by default), but I don't understand **why is the transaction trying to get the same lock again**, and, as an extra, why can't it get it (I'd expect the same transaction to be able to get the same lock of a second time) or why is this same lock been asked twice at all.

---

### Full deadlock description

```
2020-06-18T21:35:34.027779Z 566 [Note] InnoDB: Transactions deadlock detected, dumping detailed information.
2020-06-18T21:35:34.027808Z 566 [Note] InnoDB:
*** (1) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 22600376, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 577, OS thread handle 140402000619264, query id 108941776 10.42.205.242 surveda updating
UPDATE respondent_stats
     SET `count` = `count` - 1
   WHERE survey_id = OLD.survey_id
     AND questionnaire_id = IFNULL(OLD.questionnaire_id, 0)
     AND state = OLD.state
     AND disposition = OLD.disposition
     AND quota_bucket_id = IFNULL(OLD.quota_bucket_id, 0)
     AND mode = IFNULL(OLD.mode, '')
2020-06-18T21:35:34.027839Z 566 [Note] InnoDB: *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 325 page no 8 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `surveda`.`respondent_stats` trx id 22600376 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 49 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 0000000000000047; asc        G;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000005d; asc    ];;
 2: len 6; hex 616374697665; asc active;;
 3: len 9; hex 636f6e746163746564; asc contacted;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 5: len 7; hex 5b22697672225d; asc ["ivr"];;
 6: len 6; hex 00000158dab6; asc    X  ;;
 7: len 7; hex 32000001e72445; asc 2    $E;;
 8: len 4; hex 8000030c; asc     ;;

2020-06-18T21:35:34.028070Z 566 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 22600374, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 566, OS thread handle 140402422155008, query id 108941778 10.42.205.242 surveda update
INSERT INTO respondent_stats(survey_id, questionnaire_id, state, disposition, quota_bucket_id, mode, `count`)
  VALUES (NEW.survey_id, IFNULL(NEW.questionnaire_id, 0), NEW.state, NEW.disposition, IFNULL(NEW.quota_bucket_id, 0), IFNULL(NEW.mode, ''), 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1
2020-06-18T21:35:34.028092Z 566 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

RECORD LOCKS space id 325 page no 8 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `surveda`.`respondent_stats` trx id 22600374 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 49 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 0000000000000047; asc        G;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000005d; asc    ];;
 2: len 6; hex 616374697665; asc active;;
 3: len 9; hex 636f6e746163746564; asc contacted;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 5: len 7; hex 5b22697672225d; asc ["ivr"];;
 6: len 6; hex 00000158dab6; asc    X  ;;
 7: len 7; hex 32000001e72445; asc 2    $E;;
 8: len 4; hex 8000030c; asc     ;;

2020-06-18T21:35:34.028363Z 566 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 325 page no 8 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `surveda`.`respondent_stats` trx id 22600374 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 49 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 0000000000000047; asc        G;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000005d; asc    ];;
 2: len 6; hex 616374697665; asc active;;
 3: len 9; hex 636f6e746163746564; asc contacted;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 5: len 7; hex 5b22697672225d; asc ["ivr"];;
 6: len 6; hex 00000158dab6; asc    X  ;;
 7: len 7; hex 32000001e72445; asc 2    $E;;
 8: len 4; hex 8000030c; asc     ;;

2020-06-18T21:35:34.028593Z 566 [Note] InnoDB: *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

### `respondent_stats`-related triggers

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER respondents_ins
AFTER INSERT ON respondents
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO respondent_stats(survey_id, questionnaire_id, state, disposition, quota_bucket_id, mode, `count`)
  VALUES (NEW.survey_id, IFNULL(NEW.questionnaire_id, 0), NEW.state, NEW.disposition, IFNULL(NEW.quota_bucket_id, 0), IFNULL(NEW.mode, ''), 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER respondents_del
AFTER DELETE ON respondents
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE respondent_stats
      SET `count` = `count` - 1
    WHERE survey_id = OLD.survey_id
      AND questionnaire_id = IFNULL(OLD.questionnaire_id, 0)
      AND state = OLD.state
      AND disposition = OLD.disposition
      AND quota_bucket_id = IFNULL(OLD.quota_bucket_id, 0)
      AND mode = IFNULL(OLD.mode, '');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER respondents_upd
AFTER UPDATE ON respondents
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE respondent_stats
      SET `count` = `count` - 1
    WHERE survey_id = OLD.survey_id
      AND questionnaire_id = IFNULL(OLD.questionnaire_id, 0)
      AND state = OLD.state
      AND disposition = OLD.disposition
      AND quota_bucket_id = IFNULL(OLD.quota_bucket_id, 0)
      AND mode = IFNULL(OLD.mode, '');

  INSERT INTO respondent_stats(survey_id, questionnaire_id, state, disposition, quota_bucket_id, mode, `count`)
  VALUES (NEW.survey_id, IFNULL(NEW.questionnaire_id, 0), NEW.state, NEW.disposition, IFNULL(NEW.quota_bucket_id, 0), IFNULL(NEW.mode, ''), 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
END;
```

Comment: At this point, I would throw out the triggers and make a Stored Procedure to do all those tasks.  Then I would stare at it to see if things can be simplified further.